# Yii DbMessageSource App* Error

Tags: php, yii2

I am currently building a second system with yii2. It will use some tables from a Yii1 database for translation. The Yii1 project was originally translated using files but this has now been moved to the db. All the translations of the Yii1 system use one of three categories `app`,`flash`,`email` of which the vast majority use `app`.

In the Yii2 project I have the following in the web.php config file.

```
'i18n' => [
    'translations' => [      
        '*' => [
            'class' => 'yii\i18n\DbMessageSource',
            'db' => 'cdb',
            'sourceMessageTable' => 'translation_source',

            'messageTable' => 'translation',
            'forceTranslation'=>true,
        ],
    ],
],
```

All of the translations on the system that use `app` are not translated, however, all other categories are. If I change the above code to

```
'i18n' => [
    'translations' => [
        'app*' => [
```

Then I get an error for other categories but not `app` and the `app` strings are translated as expected. The error I get is

> Unable to locate message source for category 'flash'.

If however I change my config to the following, this works for all translations.

```
'i18n' => [
    'translations' => [       
        '*' => [
            'class' => 'yii\i18n\DbMessageSource',
            'db' => 'cdb',
            'sourceMessageTable' => 'translation_source',

            'messageTable' => 'translation',
            'forceTranslation' => true,
        ],
        'app*' => [
            'class' => 'yii\i18n\DbMessageSource',
            'db' => 'cdb',
            'sourceMessageTable'=>'translation_source',

            'messageTable' => 'translation',
            'forceTranslation' => true,
        ],

    ],
],
```

It just seems odd that I am having to include effectively the same code block twice. Can anyone tell me how I can achieve this in one array or is this the expected behaviour?

** Update **

I do see some mention of `*` in the docs [Docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-i18n.html#default-translation). I also see some mention of this in the [Forum](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-i18n.html#default-translation)